# Magento Shopping Cart Price Rule's Are Not Working

Tags: magento, coupon, cart-rules

Magento **Shopping Cart Price Rule's** Are Not Working.
I Have Add Coupon Code But It Not Reflect Any Output.
Please Share Any Documents For The Same.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: please send me screenshot of rule you had created.

Comment: When apply this coupon code it will return with error "Coupon code "test234" is not valid."

Comment: Make sure that all condition should be satisfied in your cart product.

Comment: Same code and same cart condition are working in the demo server but not working on the live server have u know any conflict idea.

Comment: sorry i can't say anything without checking